# GZip compression on application/xhtml+xml content type not working in IIS 7.5 / MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-7.5, gzip

I have a MVC3 site running on IIS 7.5 that has compression enabled.

The GZip compression is working on all pages of the site except for a few pages where I manually change the content type to `application/xhtml+xml` (this is necessary for various reasons) in the controller (`Response.ContentType = "application/xhtml+xml";`).

What about this content type would cause GZip not to work, and is there any way around that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`application/xhtml+xml` is not one of the built in mime types that IIS compression knows to compress. You must enable compression for this mime-type explicitly.

I'll assume you want the compression to be enabled whether it's a static file or dynamically generated. To do this you must add the mime-type to the machine level config's [`system.webServer/httpCompression`](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/httpCompression) `staticTypes` and `dynamicTypes` sections. One of the simpler ways to do this with a deployment script is to just use `appcmd.exe` like so:

**Adding support for compressing static content**

```
appcmd.exe set config -section:system.webServer/httpCompression /+"staticTypes.[mimeType='application/xhtml%%2bxml',enabled='True']" /commit:apphost
```

**Adding support for compressing dynamic content**

```
appcmd.exe set config -section:system.webServer/httpCompression /+"dynamicTypes.[mimeType='application/xhtml%%2bxml',enabled='True']" /commit:apphost
```

Obviously you can use this same approach for any other content types you might want compressed.